# Azure Logic Apps - List blobs - can I add a query

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using the Azure Logic Apps List Blobs action:
[image]

I want to know if I can add a query filter to this or do I have to list all the blobs and then filter as this will be more expensive.

Comment: There is no code to query through them, which means they can't be problematically queried directly. So, even if there were a way to query in logic apps,  i don't think adding a filter later is going be that expensive comparatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible yet. What kind of filters are you trying to use?

Would it be possible to add prefixes to your blob file names and create a logical folder structure within your Blob container?

For instance, if you named your blobs as:

```
 folder1/blobA.json
 folder1/blobB.json
 folder1/blobC.json
 folder2/blobZ.json
 folder2/blobY.json
```

This would create a logical folder structure on your Blob container with two folders. This way, the Logic App connector could list only blobs under a particular folder, i.e. with the prefix "folder1\" in the name.

In the picture below, `temp` is the container name and `myfolder/` is the blob name prefix.

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Hello. The storage structure is built up automatically from event hub data so I have no control. I am now just doing a post list filter which will do for now. Happy Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to have a direct way to achieve. Pretty much all the connectors I've dealt with are not very flexible. :(

I could not find any wildcards related [feature requests to Logic Apps](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps?query=wildcard).

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#List_blobs):

[image: List Blobs]